# Azure Static Website to CDN endpoint maping not showing

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

Here is my static website's details

Primary endpoint: `https://<mysorageac>.<zone>.web.core.windows.net/`

index doc: `index.html`

error doc: `index.html`

When I navigato to above link, it works as expected.

I created a `CDN profile` with `Standard Microsoft profile`.

Added an `endpoint` with below details

Origin type: `storage`

origin hostname: `mystorageac.blob.core.windows.net`

Origin path: `/index.html`

Origin hostheader: `mystorageac.blob.core.windows.net`

checked both `http/https`

Optimized for: `General Web Delivery`

it generated Endpoint hostname successfully with `https://myendpoint.azureedge.net`

After an hour later, I tried to navigae to https://myendpoint.azureedge.net but gives me an error 'One of the request inputs is out of range'

I tried even with full path https://myendpoint.azureedge.net/$web/index.html

I changed Origin path: `/web` - gives me "The specified resource does not exist"

Origin path: `/web/index.html` - gives me "One of the request inputs is out of range."

I tried with `purgeall` but still not working

Public Access Level is `Contain(Anonymus read access for containers and blobs)`

What else am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add static websites in Azure Storage, select **Custom origin** in the Origin type drop-down list. In the Azure portal, you need to do this from your Azure CDN profile instead of directly in your storage account.

Origin type: `Custom origin`

Origin hostname: `<mysorageac>.<zone>.web.core.windows.net`

Origin hostheader: `<mysorageac>.<zone>.web.core.windows.net`

Origin path: by default.

Sometimes, it might be a propagation issue. You need to wait for a few minutes for the CDN endpoint started working.

Ref: [Tutorial: Use Azure CDN to enable a custom domain with SSL for a static website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-custom-domain)